# QT/QML Android App, open app when click notification bar

Tags: qt, java-native-interface, qml, android-notifications, qandroidjniobject

I make an QT for Android apps. When I click button notify bar seen above in tablet. But if click notify, my apps open/focus(don' know) with black window. How to do it simply. My code is:

```
package org.ays.operation;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;


public class NotificationClient extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
     private static NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
     private static Notification.Builder m_builder;
     private static NotificationClient m_instance;
     private static PendingIntent contentIntent;
     private static Intent intent;


     public NotificationClient()
     {
         m_instance = this;
     }

     public static  void notify2()
     {
         intent = new Intent(m_instance, NotificationClient.class);
         contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(m_instance, 0, intent,
                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         if (m_notificationManager == null) {
             m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
             m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
             m_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
             m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
             m_builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
             m_builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
             m_builder.setAutoCancel(true);
         }

         m_builder.setContentText("Bla Bla");
         m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
     }
 }
```

I guest, important code is PendingIntent to open/focus main app. Other case is I don't want to use notify2 as static. Can I use it dynamic from Qt/JNI

Comment: Have you found any answers yet?

Answer (score 2):

first way:

you must change  this line

```
intent = new Intent(m_instance, NotificationClient.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivityInstance, mActivityInstance.getClass());
```

and

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(m_instance, 0, intent,
                                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mActivityInstance, 0, intent,
                                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

attention mActivityInstance is your mainActivity.

I set my mActivityInstance from c++ and with JNI like below:

```
const QAndroidJniObject m_JavaNotification("com/falsinsoft/qtandroidtools/AndroidNotification",
                   "(Landroid/app/Activity)V",
                   QtAndroid::androidActivity().object<jobject>());
```

and in my AndroidNotification.java:

```
public class AndroidNotification {
private final Activity mActivityInstance;

public AndroidNotification(Activity ActivityInstance)
{
    mActivityInstance = ActivityInstance;
}
}
```

second way(I dont sure this solve your problem!):
change this line in you manifiset.xml:

```
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="YourProjectName" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

to:

```
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="your java class extend from QtActivity" android:label="YourProjectName" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```